# Spyder. Error al debuggear UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 22: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python-3.x, depuración, anaconda, spyder

Al debuggear código con spyder 5.2 Python 3.6 me sale el siguiente error:

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Python_v1\lib\tokenize.py", line 390, in find_cookie
    line_string = line.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 22: invalid continuation byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  File "<string>", line unknown
SyntaxError: invalid or missing encoding declaration for 'c:\\users\\jruizguillen\\acciona s.a\\control de activos - documentos\\relevantes mensuales\\precierre\\yte indisponibilidad\\actualizar_tabla_disp_real_mtd.py'
```

Sin embargo, al correr el script completo, sin tratar de debuggearlo ejecuta correctamente. ¿Alguna idea qué puede estar pasando?

He eliminado caracteres "extraños" ('ñ', acentos,...) y tratado de correr el script desde uno nuevo sin éxito.

¡Gracias!

Adjunto más abajo un ejemplo del código por si ayuda con el error.

```
import mysql.connector
import os, os.path
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

# Conexion con la base de datos
miConexion = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='111.111.111.111',
    user= 'whoever',
    passwd='whatever',
    db='database')

lista_insert = list()
deleted_files=0

# Se sacan las horas de cada mes
cur = miConexion.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM disponibildad_yte.mes")
horas_mes = cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: No compartes tu código así que no podemos responder. Te sirve esto? https://stackoverflow.com/q/40437006/236345

Comment: Gracias, @Alfabravo, no funcionó. Comparto mi código por aquí: